# Memory efficient way to aggregate values that have the same key

Tags: bash, shell, csv, scripting

I have a CSV file that contains some duplicate keys. I want to deduplicate these keys and keep all their values together in one raw.

So if the input is

```
a,foo
b,bar
a,baz
```

The output should be

```
a,foo baz
b,bar
```

Comment: Welcome to SO David, kindly do add your efforts into your post too in code tags, happy learning.

Comment: if you don't presort by keys, all data need to be kept in memory to find matches.  Memory efficient way is sorting data first...

Comment: @karakfa, BINGO, I had added that solution too in my post sir :)

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** Without using array, 1st sorting the Input_file(to make all 1st fields consecutive occurrence) and then collecting the values as per OP's request.(this could be memory efficient)

```
sort -s -t, -k1,1 Input_file |
awk -F, '
prev!=$1 && prev{
  print prev FS val;
  prev=val=""}
{
  val=val?val OFS $NF:$NF;
  prev=$1
}
END{
  if(val){
    print prev FS val}
}'
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Following `awk` may help you here. It may not give you output in same order in which 1st field is coming in your Input_file(this could be more efficient compare to 3rd one as it is using only single array).

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $NF:$NF} END{for(i in a){print i FS a[i]}}' Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** Following `awk` will give you output in same order in which 1st field came in Input_file.

```
awk -F, '
!b[$1]++{
  c[++count]=$1}
{
  a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $NF:$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[i] FS a[c[i]]}
}' Input_file
```

Comment: you can change `prev","val` to `prev FS val`.

Comment: @karakfa, good catch sir, done that now in all of the 3 solutions, cheers.